# identifier "do" is undefined

Tags: c++

I've had to ask this question as I can't find any matching results. There are plenty of `identifier "x" is undefined` but none for "Do".

So, I get the error message: `identifier "Do" is undefined`, and don't know how to address it.

I previously had the error: `identifier "string" is undefined`, which I addressed by changing it to `std::string` and adding `#include <string>`. I tried the same approach for "Do" but Do is not a member of `namespace std`.

It might be worth pointing out that I'm working in Visual C++ and am editing the Half-Life 2 source code.

Can anyone help me understand why I get this error and how I might address it? Thanks!

Comment: You should quote the offending code, at the very least. For C++, the proper keyword is `do`. Casing matters.

Comment: C++ is case sensitive, so don't do `Do` but do `do` :)

Comment: <facepalm> yes, thanks, that was it

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing keywords with types. In C++, `string` is a type introduced by `<string>` which resides in `namespace std`.

`do` is a keyword (totally different) and it's lowercase (not `Do`). You don't need to include anything for keywords, they should be directly recognizable by the compiler.